# How does this example violate Liskov substitution principle, which then causes violation of the open-closed principle?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, software-engineering, design-patterns

From [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://flylib.com/books/en/4.444.1.64/1/) by Robert Martin,

> Listing   10-1.   A   violation   of  LSP causing a    violation  of  OCP
>
> ```
> struct    Point   {double x,  y;}
> public    enum    ShapeType   {square,    circle};
> public    class   Shape
> {
>       private ShapeType   type;
>       public  Shape(ShapeType t){type =   t;}
>       public  static  void    DrawShape(Shape s)
>       {
>               if(s.type   ==  ShapeType.square)
>                       (s  as  Square).Draw();
>               else    if(s.type   ==  ShapeType.circle)
>                       (s  as  Circle).Draw();
>       }
> }
> public    class   Circle  :   Shape
> {
>       private Point   center;
>       private double  radius;
>       public  Circle()    :   base(ShapeType.circle)  {}
>       public  void    Draw()  {/* draws   the circle  */}
> }
> public    class   Square  :   Shape
> {
>       private Point   topLeft;
>       private double  side;
>       public  Square()    :   base(ShapeType.square)  {}
>       public  void    Draw()  {/* draws   the square  */}
> }
> ```
>
> `DrawShape()` violates    OCP.    It
>   must    know    about   every   possible    derivative  of  the  Shape  class,
>   and it  must    be  changed whenever    new derivatives of   Shape  are
>   created.
>
> The   fact    that     `Square`   and  `Circle`   cannot  be  substituted for `Shape`     is  a
>   violation   of  LSP.    This    violation   forced  the violation   of  OCP by
>   DrawShape . Thus,   a   violation   of  LSP is  a   latent  violation   of  OCP.

How does it violate Liskov substitution principle (LSP)?
(In particular, why can `Square`    and  `Circle`   not be  substituted for  `Shape`?)

How does violation of LSP cause violation of the open-closed principle (OCP)? (I can  see it directly violates OCP, but I can't understand how violation of LSP causes violation of OCP.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The listing does not appear to be a good illustration of LSP violation, since no clear reason is given why the draw method couldn't be a virtual method of Shape. If it was, then there would be no need to do any type query in drawShape: calling draw would work for all subclasses of Shape.

The Liskov Substitution Principle is typically described in terms of *contracts*. For example: the contract of the square root function **requires** that the input is non-negative and **ensures** that the square of the output is equal to the input.

Hence, an overridden method in a subclass is substitutable for the corresponding method in the superclass if it:

- **requires** no more of its input than the superclass contract
- **ensures** no less of its output

A subclass is LSP-conforming if all its methods are LSP conforming.

Hence, a better illustration of LSP violation might be a rotate method, in which all shapes except Square can be rotated by any angle, but Square is only rotatable by some multiple of 90% (such a requirement would actually demonstrate that the Square should not be a subclass of Shape).

In general, LSP violation causes OCP violation because there is no meaningful action that a 'closed' function can take without needing knowledge of specific subclasses in the type hierarchy.

The standard example of this is to have a Circle class be a subclass of an Ellipse class that has a `resize(xaxis,yaxis)` method. Unless the semantics of resize are so diluted as to be largely useless ('maybe resize yourself or throw an exception') then subclasses can end up in a state that is inconsistent with anything meaningful/useful to the 'closed' function that is calling its methods.

A good discussion of the LSP (including the 'Circle-Ellipse' issue) can be found [here](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/oop/ht00/Slides/CircleVrsEllipse.ps.gz)